# How to solve this complex integral?

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I need to solve the equation

$I = \int_0^u\frac{dx}{(a + bx + i\epsilon)^2}$,

where $a$ and $b$ are real, and functions of $u$ ($u$ is another variable that I have to perform another integral after). I tried to use the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem,

$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)dx}{x-x_0+i\epsilon} = P\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)dx}{x-x_0} + i\pi \delta(x - x_0)$

I don't know if I can directly use this theorem, once the integration limits in $I$  are different. If there is no problem, I have the Principal Value, $\frac{u}{a(a-bu)}$, but I am not sure about the argument of delta function. There is another way to proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mathematica 11.3 thinks it should be
$$
I=\frac{u}{(a+i \varepsilon)(a+bu+i \varepsilon)}
$$

Comment: Yes, I already tried on Mathematica... But this $i \epsilon$ is used to avoid the singularity, and the program treats it as a simple variable. That's why I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: What singularity are you trying to avoid? There are none in your integral range.

Comment: In this case there are none singularity because $i \epsilon$ avoids it... My question is how to solve this integral, to obtain an expression that is a function of $u$!

Comment: The epsilon *is* a simple variable. You can evaluate the integral in closed form and then take the limit:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \int_0^u  \frac {dx} {(a + b x + i \epsilon)^2} = \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}  \frac u {(a + i \epsilon) (a + b u + i \epsilon)} = \frac u {a(a + b u)}.$$
The limit exists as long as $x=−a/b$ is not one of the endpoints of $[0, u]$. Note that your Sokhotski–Plemelj is not quite correct: by linearity, the last term cannot be independent of $f$.

Comment: Perhaps your question is about something different, possibly about the distributional limit of a functional. But you haven't specified what functional you're talking about; once you write $\int_0^u$, this is just an integral of an ordinary function.